# JSF api version

Tags: jsf-2, facelets, ajax4jsf

When I want to turn on server I got this warning.

> com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor processComponent
>   AVERTISSEMENT: JSF1029 : La version de l’application est 2.0 (soit explicitement par la version du fichier /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml ou par l’absence de fichier /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml). Toutefois, la classe «org.ajax4jsf.taglib.html.facelets.ActionParamHandler» dépend d’une classe de facelet héritée.  L’artefact de facelet représenté par cette classe ne sera pas enregistré.

I ve tried many version of JSF-api and JSP-impl. Always the same problem. I am using Eclipse.

Comment: Starter's tip: Change your development environment to English. There are SO MANY more valuable hits in Google when you copypaste a genuine English error message in the search field.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
       http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_1_2.xsd"
 version="1.2"> Be careful while using the version ; for me it was 2.0 and in fact i was working with 1.2. Be careful while using faces-config.xml